# I am getting forbidden error code in my reactjs app with Post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a nodejs api that uses jwt to grant access to users. Everything works fine when I used postman to make these api calls.
I am trying to integrate the api with my reactjs and I keep getting `403 forbidden error`. I am using axios to make the post request.
I removed the jwt verification middleware that I created in my nodejs and the logic behind it and the post request worked fine in react. That means that the problem is from my jwt implementation in reactjs. Kindly help me out, please:

Node codes

```
/create new post
const createNewPost = async (req, res) =>{
const user = await User.findById(req.user.userId);
if(!user){
    return res.status(404).json('User not found'); 
 }

if(user.isBlocked === true){
    return res.status(500).json('Sorry, you can not make a post at this moment');
  };
   const newPost = new Post(req.body );
   try{
    //push post to userPost array to create user-post relationship
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.body.username);
    currentUser.userPosts.push(newPost);

    //save new post and user
    const savedPost = await newPost.save();
    await currentUser.save();
  
    res.status(200).json(savedPost);
 }catch(err){
   res.status(500).json(err);
};
};
```

Post route

```
 router.post('/', verify, createNewPost);
```

App.js

```
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts');
```

Reactjs codes

```
export default function Write() {

const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
const {user} = useContext(Context);
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)



//handles the submitting of post and uploading of images
const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
e.preventDefault();
setIsFetching(true)
const newPost = {
    username: user.user.userId,
    title,
    description,
    categories,
   
};
if(file){                    
    const data = new FormData();
    const filename = Date.now() + file.name;
    data.append("name", filename);
    data.append("file", file);
    newPost.postPhoto = filename;

    try{
        await axios.post("/upload",  data, { credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{authorization: "Bearer" + user.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
    })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    }

   try{
    setIsFetching(true)
    const response = await axios.post("/posts",  newPost, { credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
        headers:{authorization: "Bearer" + user.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
    },)
   
    window.location.replace("/post/" + response.data._id, )
   }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
   
  }
};
```

Everything works fine in postman including the jwt verification before making a post. However, it doesn't work in reactjs. If I remove the jwt verification middleware and logics from the backend, I can make post request from reactjs.

Comment: Open the browser dev tools, go to the network tab, and then look at what network calls your client code is actually making. Good bet it's the preflight `OPTIONS` call that's getting rejected, which means that even if the `POST` _would_ work, it won't, because the browser needs that `OPTIONS` call to succeed in order to determine whether it's even allowed to use `POST` at all.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.. I don't really understand what you're saying. I checked my network tab and I can see that the upload image call went through with status code of 200. When it got to post, it failed. Is there something else I need to check?

Comment: What does "when it got to post" mean? Make sure you're showing "all" activity, clear the network log, and then perform your post: how many network calls does it make, and which of those fail (and then talk about that in your post because those are very question-relevant details).

Comment: Every other calls went through except /post/ route. Post is the post route coming from my nodejs backend.

Comment: Then it's time to rather drastically update your post because if your node server's post route is the problem, show the [mcve] code that connects to _that_ and then show the [mcve] code for your node server's post handler, too. If the problem is a client/server call, the question should focus on that call, showing both the client and server handling of it. Run through the MCVE exercise first (e.g. you don't need those axios calls to _test_ here, remove them and hardcode the data you know should work in the server post call, etc.)

Comment: And then do the same reducation on the server side: your `createNewPost` doesn't throw a 403 anywhere, so we know the post never gets there: start debugging by putting a `(req, res, next) => { ... }` in your app.post chain before the verify call, and see what's in `req`.

Comment: I actually checked response section in my network tab, I can see that I am getting 'token not valid'. That means I have not properly implemented the jwt since it works in postman very well once I use a valid jwt token.

Comment: Sounds like a little debugging went a long way, then, and you can probably delete this question since the next steps are just "fixing the code that you now know is wrong"

Comment: Well, I will still leave it because I am yet to resolve my issue. I can see my token in the header. It is the right token. The token is in my localstorage. I can access it via console.log inside my right code. I can see it. But somehow, I keep getting 'token is not valid' error message.